# find first and last value within a sequence in r

Tags: r

I have a sequence and then times that are recorded within each sequence. I am trying to find the max value of time that is recorded with its corresponding sequence. Example below:

```
    Seq    seconds
1    1       1
2    1       2
3    1       3
4    1       4
5    2       1
6    2       2 
7    3       1
8    3       2
9    3       3
10   3       4
11   3       5
```

I would like a result that tells me the max time that was recorded in each sequence.

```
Seq   Time
 1     4
 2     2
 3     5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
dt2 <- dt %>%
  arrange(Seq, seconds) %>%
  group_by(Seq) %>%
  slice(n())
dt2
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Seq [3]
    Seq seconds
  <int>   <int>
1     1       4
2     2       2
3     3       5
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "    Seq    seconds
1    1       1
                 2    1       2
                 3    1       3
                 4    1       4
                 5    2       1
                 6    2       2 
                 7    3       1
                 8    3       2
                 9    3       3
                 10   3       4
                 11   3       5",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Time = max(seconds)), Seq]
#   Seq Time
#1:   1    4
#2:   2    2
#3:   3    5
```